# C# Make every letter have a Space behind it

Tags: c#

I have written a code that should write a Space after every Character. But it dont looks like it is working.

```
foreach (char c in texttoencodedecode.Text)
{
    c += " ";
    texttoencodedecode.Text += c
}
```

Sadly this isnt working. The c += " "; outputs a Error.
Hope you can help me
Cheers.

Comment: possible one liner `texttoencodedecode.Text = string.Join(" ", texttoencodedecode.Text.ToArray());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` can only contain a single character, so attempting to append another character to it will result in an error, unless you convert it to a string.

```
foreach (char c in texttoencodedecode.Text)
{
    string s = c + " ";
    texttoencodedecode.Text += s;
}
```

Or

```
foreach (char c in texttoencodedecode.Text)
{
    texttoencodedecode.Text += (c + ' ');
}
```

If you want to be clever though you can use linq:

```
texttoencode.Text = new string( texttoencode.Text.SelectMany( c => new char[] { c, ' '}).ToArray());
```

This avoids the continuous reallocations of strings.

Comment: Thank you for the Respond. is there a Posibillity to convert c into a string so i can replace the char if i want to? would be amazing

Answer (score 1):

The `char c` is a single character (and it is something that is fixed, you can't have a zero-length `char`, you can't have a two-length `char`), so you can't "add" to it. You can't even modify the variable you are doing the `foreach` on (so you can't modify `texttoencodedecode.Text`), you'll get an `Exception` at runtime. The solution is to write to a new temporary variable, `temp` and then reassign `texttoencodedecode.Text` with `temp`

```
string temp = string.Empty;

foreach (char c in texttoencodedecode.Text)
{
    temp += c;
    temp += " ";
}

texttoencodedecode.Text = temp;
```

Now... Normally you should use a `StringBuilder` for this, because "appending" many times to a `string` is "bad" (`string`s aren't built for it):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char c in texttoencodedecode.Text)
{
    sb.Append(c);
    sb.Append(' ');
}

texttoencodedecode.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I, guess you are wanting this,

Input: Hello

output: H e l l o

Here, c is a character.
You are adding space(" ") with c which is not possible.

You can try this way(hint):

Take a empty string(temp)

foreach (char c in texttoencodedecode.Text)
{

```
Add c with temp
Add space with temp
```

}

Assign texttoencodedecode.Text = temp